# how to reduce GPU/TPU memory usage for reusing encoder (e.g. RNN/Tensor2Tensor/etc.)?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, google-cloud-tpu

I have a list (e.g. 1000) of phrases (each phrase contains one or more words) to encode. 
I reuse a same encoder (e.g. RNN/Tensor2Tensor/etc.) for each of the phrase (which means they share the learned parameters in the encoder). 
As a result, the size of parameters to be learned is small since it is only single encoder but the graph size become huge because the list is pretty long. 
Can anyone gives me some suggestions that how to reduce the memory in this case (I think it is because the graph just repeat same computation sub-graph (the encoder) over and over but those sub-graph share parameters)? 
Thank you.

Comment: Hey, Have you tried word embeddings?